# Spring boot rest api unit test for controller

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

[image]

I have two controllers, one for users and one for roles. I have written test for the user controller, but when i try to run test it it gives me the following error:

> "Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'uk.co.circuare.cube.service.user.repository.RoleRepository'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}"

I am using mockito

```
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository repository; [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I have used two repositories in my usercontroller:

@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;

@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

Comment: Obviously, some of your beans are missing a dependency... It is not clear from the given code, which bean it is. You've to provide more code.

Comment: Because of your repository is not in base package

Comment: rolerepository is used in my role controller, but i was write any test for role, my application running ok, but it is test

Comment: @faheem what should i need to do ?

Comment: I have used two repository in my usercontroller

Autowired
private UserRepository repository;
Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is pretty straightforward — you need to provide every bean used in your controller class for the Application Context in your test class.

You have mentioned an error saying that `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'uk.co.circuare.cube.service.user.repository.RoleRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.`. It means that there is no bean of type `RoleRepository` in your test Application Context.

You're using the `@MockBean` annotation. It will replace any existing bean of the same type in the application context. If no bean of the same type is defined, a new one will be added.  I would recommend you to check the details on the mock annotation, which you're using in this article: [Mockito.mock() vs @Mock vs @MockBean](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean)

To resolve your issue, your test class should look like the following:

```java
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository repository;

    @MockBean
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have to mock `RoleRepository` in your test class.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;

    @Mock
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Mock
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    ...
}
```